# Xenserver Virtual Adapter Limit

Tags: virtual-machines, xenserver

My understanding is that as of Xenserver 6.5 and earlier versions, you can only have 7 virtual network adapters per VM. Is there any known (probably unsupported) way around this limitation?

My use case is that we are setting up a NIDS, and instead of spinning up another VM for the rest of our VLANs, I would like to add another couple of adapters to the existing one, though this would put us at 9 necessary VLANs that this VM needs to access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every template in XenServer has a "hint" about max number of VIFs. This only restricts XenCenter GUI, and you can easily add more NICs from command line. See `xe help vif-create`.

You can also change a template. Templates are internally tar files, so they can be accessed easily. Look for *allowed-VIF-devices* parameter in XML file.

Comment: Thanks. I've been doing a bit of research about it as well and I've read and heard from other team members that going over the limit is bad, but with little reasoning and I can't find any documentation stating that going over the 7 NIC maximum per guest is bad. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: I never ran into any problem with VIFs > 7 configurations. I've used them on production in HVM mode running FreeBSD (pfSense) and likely on other test VMs. IIRC there's a hard limit of 31 VIFs per VM in Xapi.